# How can I use namespaces in a SQL XML query with the "nodes" command?

Tags: sql, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to query fields from the following XML query, (which is really a web service call):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="[schema]" xmlns:xsd="[shema]" xmlns:soap="[schema]">
  <soap:Body>
    <RunPackage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xmlDoc>
        <Request>
          <SubscriberCode>543253</SubscriberCode>
          <CompanyCode>54325</CompanyCode>
          <BranchName>TestBranchName</BranchName>
          <TempWorksUserName>TempWorksUserName</TempWorksUserName>
[...]
```

With the following XML Query:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('[schema]' AS soap2, DEFAULT '[schema]')

SELECT TransactionID, T2.Loc.query('data(Request/SubscriberCode)') as 'SubscriberCode'
FROM TempWorksRequest
CROSS APPLY RequestXML.nodes('soap2:Envelope/soap2:Body/RunPackage/xmlDoc') as T2(Loc)
```

It runs but does not return any retults!

If I build the same query but remove the namespace stuff THEN it works. For example, the following works fine:

> <xmlDoc>
>   <Request>
>     <SubscriberCode>543253</SubscriberCode>
>     <CompanyCode>54325</CompanyCode>
>     <BranchName>TestBranchName</BranchName>
>   [...]

SQL Query:

> -- Define a namespace for MITS so we can use the MITS namespace. 
>   WITH XMLNAMESPACES('[schema]'
>   AS soap2, DEFAULT
>   '[schema]')
>
> SELECT TransactionID,
>     T2.Loc.query('data(Request/SubscriberCode)') as 'SubscriberCode' 
>   FROM  TempWorksRequest
>   CROSS APPLY RequestXML.nodes('xmlDoc') as T2(Loc)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue thanks for Mark! Namespaces must be explicitly declared.

New WORKING query:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('[URI1]' AS ns, '[URI2]' AS soap) 

SELECT TransactionID, 
    T2.Loc.query('data(ns:SubscriberCode)') as 'SubscriberCode',
FROM TempWorksRequest
CROSS APPLY RequestXML.nodes('soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns:RunPackage/ns:xmlDoc/ns:Request') as T2(Loc)
```