# XML query values from xml nodes only return one record

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, sql-server-2016, sqlxml

I have used a number of sources to get to this point:

[How to query values from xml nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712864/how-to-query-values-from-xml-nodes) and http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e6ed/1

[T-Sql xml query with namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909987/t-sql-xml-query-with-namespace)

[How to query a specific tag from XML field data in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508101/how-to-query-a-specific-tag-from-xml-field-data-in-sql)

[How can I use namespaces in a SQL XML query with the "nodes" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982910/how-can-i-use-namespaces-in-a-sql-xml-query-with-the-nodes-command)

[How to query for Xml values and attributes from table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165213/how-to-query-for-xml-values-and-attributes-from-table-in-sql-server)

I have the follow XML source:
I have removed the actual imagedata because of size constraints

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <EmbeddedImages>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="RioTinto">
      <MIMEType>image/jpeg</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>
      </ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="Palweb">
      <MIMEType>image/jpeg</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>
      </ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="SABS1">
      <MIMEType>image/png</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>
      </ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="SABS2">
      <MIMEType>image/jpeg</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>
      </ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="ISC">
      <MIMEType>image/png</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>
      </ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="ISO_9001_ISO_14001_COL">
      <MIMEType>image/jpeg</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>
      </ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="GSCMPMCHeader">
      <MIMEType>image/png</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>
      </ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="ISO_9001_ISO_14001_COL1">
      <MIMEType>image/png</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>
      </ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
    <EmbeddedImage Name="TopEmployer2019">
      <MIMEType>image/png</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>
      </ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
  </EmbeddedImages>
</Report>
```

I run the following Query on it:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES
(
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition'
)
SELECT lvV.Name,
       reportdata.item.value('(./EmbeddedImage)[1]', 'VARCHAR(2000)') AS EmbeddedImages,
       reportdata.item.value('(./EmbeddedImage/@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(2000)') AS Name,
       reportdata.item.value('(./EmbeddedImage/MIMEType)[1]', 'VARCHAR(2000)') AS MIMEType,
       reportdata.item.value('(./EmbeddedImage/ImageData)[1]', 'VARCHAR(2000)') AS ImageData
FROM @LysvanVerslae AS lvV
    cross APPLY lvV.VerslagRDL.nodes('/Report/EmbeddedImages') AS reportdata(item);
```

Why does it only return one row as the results instead of 9.
It does not matter whether I remove the `value('(./` or not

[image]

Comment: Cause you're looping EmbeddedImages. You need: lvV.VerslagRDL.nodes('/Report/EmbeddedImages/EmbeddedImage')

Comment: Will you add it as a answer?

Comment: Sure, added an answer with a bit more text :)

Answer (score 1):

You're looping EmbeddedImages.
You need to add the repeating node like:

```sql
... 
lvV.VerslagRDL.nodes('/Report/EmbeddedImages/EmbeddedImage') AS reportdata(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you are need to go down to `EmbeddedImage` in the `.nodes` call. But then you also need to remove that from the `.values` call, as you already went down to that level.

Further improvements:

- `./` is pointless, it's the default anyway to start from the current node.
- You should use `text()` in order to pull out the inner text of a node, rather than relying on implicit conversion, for performance reasons.
- `@Attribute` does not require `[1]` for the current node, because it's guaranteed unique.
- Choose better data types.

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES
(
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition'
)
SELECT lvV.Name,
       reportdata.item.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(2000)') AS EmbeddedImages,
       reportdata.item.value('@Name', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS Name,
       reportdata.item.value('(MIMEType/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(200)') AS MIMEType,
       reportdata.item.value('(ImageData/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS ImageData
FROM LysvanVerslae AS lvV
cross APPLY lvV.VerslagRDL.nodes('/Report/EmbeddedImages/EmbeddedImage') AS reportdata(item);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/SeFRA-hr)